# Catch Right-Click AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, contextmenu, right-click

Is it possible to catch a right-click inside of flash (AS3)?

No JQuery/JavaScript.

I need to pause gameplay when a right-click is caught, so I don't so much want to disable the context-menu as I do just want to tell that a right-click has happened.  Is there an EventListener I can add?  Any other ideas?

UPDATE:
I need the event to be triggered as they are actually right clicking, not just after the context-menu has disappeared.

Comment: http://3l3373.com/flash-as3-right-click-context-menu/ maybe this helps

Comment: Unfortunately no, that only manages to read the click after the context menu has disappeared.  I need the event to be triggered as they are actually right clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two ways to capture a right click event:

1. For a web browser application: [Use JavaScript](http://www.uza.lt/2007/08/19/solved-right-click-in-as3/).  You can't do it directly in Flash, because you can't disable the context menu.
2. For a desktop application: Deploy as an AIR application. AIR has a [RIGHT_CLICK MouseEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#RIGHT_CLICK) built in.

There's no step three. :(

P.S: That is, if [menuSelect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#event%3amenuSelect) really doesn't work for you - the documentation says it is triggered *before* the menu is opened.

Answer (score 1):

Just as weltraumpirat reported, the only way to capture the Right Click event is if you are building your application to be deployed as an AIR application if you want to keep it all native to the Flash Platform Architecture; otherwise you will need to use some other language in conjunction with Flash to capture the event (i.e. JavaScript).

FYI, here is the API reference for the MouseEvent Class that contains information about the RightClick event: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

Without Javascript! 
Yes it works fine.

I tell you:
If you are use Flex- or Flash-Builder than you need add rightClick from root application tag:
example: `<s:Applikation .... RightClick="appRightClick (event)">`
Than you need to switch off contextmenu to null.

And you add bordercontainer or view than add rightClick with any rightClick-function than you need to add menu from mx.controls.Menu and menu1 needs to listen to rightClick to appRightClick (event)

Because it doesn't access from Flash Player Contextmenu.

I hope it because your flash applikation works for rightClick :)

Comment: I'd like to do it in normal AS3 and not in FLEX

Comment: nope look my solution :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259135/new-right-click-without-javascript-rightclick-js

Comment: Wow that's awesome, thanks so much!  I'm not sure if they'll allow that submission though...Can you think of a question to post and then post that answer as a solution to that question?  Right now it's just a blog post.

Comment: you are welcome :) i hope you that you can develop my simple right click on Flec Applikation using MX Version.  it is very easy. :)