# Check Mouse Status

Tags: actionscript-3, events, mouse

I am trying to check when the right button of the mouse is up. I have tried to create an EventListener for RIGHT_MOUSE_UP, but it returns an error (1119: Access of possibly undefined property RIGHT_MOUSE_UP through a reference with static type Class.), while MOUSE_UP doesn't work. How I can do this?

EDIT:

```
public function mouseOverHandler( evt:MouseEvent )
{
if( evt.buttonDown == true )
        {
            this.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseRelease);

            curState_ = 2;

            if( animated_ == true )
            {
                // Stuff
            }

            else
            {
                // Stuff
            }
        }

        else
        {
// Stuff
        }

        dispatchEvent(new CustomButtonEvent(CustomButtonEvent.OVER));
    }
```

Comment: Added the relevant code.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702543/catch-right-click-as3

Comment: So there's no way to do that?

Comment: You have two options, depending on if you're developing for browser or AIR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this tip http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=3253

he said you need FP 11.2 beta for using 'MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK' event.